# glCreateShader fails with error 1286 when automatic reference counting is enabled

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl, shader

I've got an OSX app that uses OpenGL framework.  Everything works fine until I turn on automatic reference counting.  As soon as I turn on automatic reference counting `glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)` fails with error 1286. Anybody have any idea what would cause this? Any idea how to get automatic reference counting to play nice with OpenGL? (Shouldn't that just work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an objective c expert, but I have tooled around with it a little bit.

I seem to recall that if you use automatic reference counting but you have left some `release` statements in your code, it can cause objects to be de-allocated unexpectedly.

Comment: You're answer is pretty close and lead me find a fix.  My NSOpenGLView pointer was a variable in a C++ class.  For some reason, even though my C++ class is still allocated and around, and the m_View pointer is set to the view, seems that automatic reference counting was probably being deleted and that would delete the context. By moving the m_View pointer to be a global, the problem goes away.